# highcharts tooltip z-index

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to get the highcharts tooltip to have a zIndex using `useHTML` to position it over another HTML element.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sDu8V/

I'd like the tooltip to go over the pink box - instead of under it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/sDu8V/1/

Required CSS:

```
.highcharts-container {
  position: inherit !important;
}
.highcharts-tooltip {
  z-index: 9998;
}
```

Thanks to **@Piotr**, updated design for [4.1.x](http://jsfiddle.net/sDu8V/1/).

Comment: Sorry @Paweł Fus, but I don't see how this is solving the issue. On the jsfiddle I still get the pink box covering the tooltips with no change to get the tooltip over it. I tested it on Chrome and Safari. Could you please check and confirm?

Comment: Hover IE -> tooltip is displayed over pink box, ant that was the question, as I remember.

Comment: I made minor changes to your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/sDu8V/24/ Removed margin and improved content Tooltip.

Comment: Thanks! Caused probably by changes between 2.x and 4.x ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have **only** the tooltip to get rendered over the pink box because the whole chart is rendered in a single SVG object that is either **totallly** over or beneath your pink both.

What you can do is to render the whole chart over the pink box by making it background transparent.

Your chart:

```
chart: { backgroundColor:'transparent' }
```

Your div should also be beneath the chart:

```
<div id="box" style="z-index:0"></div>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7TcJ6/

Answer (score 1):

if you are searching solution when you have no access to the tooltip class so you can do this, paste this code below before your `Highchart.chart` or component initialization (btw works for React as well)

```
(function (H) {
  H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, "getLabel", function (proceed) {
    var t = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    if (this.container) {
      H.css(this.container, { zIndex: 1301 });
    }

    return t;
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

it works for me, in my case tooltip is `outside:true` so its rendered in its own portal, but you still can put its class `highcharts-tooltip-container` in your global CSS file

I hope it will help to someone

Comment: While I'll probably use non-prototype-altering final solution, this was VERY helpful for debugging a not-visible tooltip!

Comment: non-prototype-altering final solution? It would be great to add some links to the solution you talking about